# JavaScript filter arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm taking online JavaScript courses and I'm curious about one of the tasks:

We'r provided with an initial array (the first argument in the destroyer function), followed by one or more arguments. We have to remove all elements from the initial array that are of the same value as these arguments.

Here's my solution, but it doesn't works:

```js
 function destroyer(arr) {
   // Separating the array from the numbers, that are for filtering; 
   var filterArr = [];
   for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
     filterArr.push(arguments[i]);
   }

   // This is just to check if we got the right numbers
   console.log(filterArr);

   // Setting the parameters for the filter function
   function filterIt(value) {
       for (var j = 0; j < filterArr.length; j++) {
         if (value === filterArr[j]) {
           return false;
         }
       }
     }
     // Let's check what has been done
   return arguments[0].filter(filterIt);
 }

 destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3);
```

I was able to find a solution, however it doesn't makes any sense to me, that's why I'm posting this question; can you please tell me why the following code works:

```js
function destroyer(arr) {
  // Separating the array from the numbers, that are for filtering; 
  var filterArr = [];
  for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    filterArr.push(arguments[i]);
  }

  // This is just to check if we got the right numbers
  console.log(filterArr);

  // Setting the parameters for the filter function
  function filterIt(value) {
      for (var j = 0; j < filterArr.length; j++) {
        if (value === filterArr[j]) {
          return false;
        }
        // This true boolean  is what makes the code to run and I can't                  // understand why. I'll highly appreciate your explanations.
      }
      return true;
    }
    // Let's check what has been done
  return arguments[0].filter(filterIt);
}

destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3);
```

Thank you for the heads up!

Comment: The function in `filter` needs to return some value. If it’s truthy (e.g. `true`), the element is kept, if it’s falsy (e.g. `false`), it’s removed. You’re only returning `false` or `undefined` (automatically) which is falsy.

Comment: The function passed to the `filter` method must return `true` if you want to retain the element. If it only returns `false` it will remove everything. _Not_ returning a value is treated as if returning `false`.

Answer (score 2):

You code is not working because you are not returning `true`.

`Array.filter` expects a boolean value as return value. If `true`, it will add to resulting dataset. If `false`, is will skip.

Since you are not returning anything, it returns `undefined` as default and `undefined` is falsey. Hence your return array would be blank.

As per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter),

> filter() calls a provided callback function once for each element in an array, and constructs a new array of all the values for which callback returns **a value that coerces to true**.

Answer (score 2):

`filter` is an Array native function. It creates a new array with all elements that pass a given test. The test function must return a boolean value, if `true` that value is not filtered out and if `false`,  it is filtered out.

Go through the docs:
[Filter- Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

The correct solution that you have posted, has a valid test function for filtering the given array, that returns `true` and `false`, for the specific use case (here being the logic of eliminating numbers provided as arguments).

Your implementation misses returning `true` (which is returning `undefined`, a falsey value in Javscript, hence all of the values are filtered out and you get an empty array.

**Note:** `true` here refers to all truthy values in JS and `false` refers to all falsy values in JS.

Answer (score 2):

Read what Rajesh wrote, it is easy to understand how `filter()` works.

Also you do not actually need a helper function.
This code is more than enough:
**Edit:** *even less code as suggested by Rajesh*

```
function destroyer(arr) {

  for (var i = 1, filterArr = []; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    filterArr.push(arguments[i]);
  }

  return arguments[0].filter(function(v) {
    return filterArr.indexOf(v)===-1
  });
}

var result = destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 5, 3], 2, 3);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for credit. You can replace `return filterArr.indexOf(v)>-1` as your callback for filter.

Answer (score 2):

You might do the same job with a relatively simple code by utilizing `Array.prototype.reduce()` as follows;

ES6

```js
var destroyer = (a,...f) => a.reduce((p,c) => f.includes(c) ? p : p.concat(c),[]);
console.log(destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3));
```

or in ES5

```js
function destroyer(a){
  var f = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,1);
  return a.reduce(function(p,c){
                    return f.indexOf(c) !== -1 ? p : p.concat(c);
                  },[]);
}
console.log(destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3));
```

Answer (score 1):

The filter callback has to return a boolean to either keep the element or to drop it so true says that the value passed your check.

A detailed description of the filter prototype can be found here.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter